# How to get input values from variables that are in a function within another module and use them?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have one module that has a login function and forwarding to different menus function, and the other module which I have trouble with. The second module should be used only by the currently logged in user. (users with their credentials are defined inside of a json file)

My idea was to get the values that the user enters in the login function in a different module and use it to show the options in the program that are only available to that user (which should be done in the second module).

Therefore, how can I get the input values from the other function that's within a different module.

#### this is what I've tried

```
from src.system_login.login_1 import username, password
```

#### this is the function within another module that I want to get the username and password values from so that I could use it in another module

```
def login_1():

    signed_in= False

    while signed_in == False:
        username= input("Username: ")
        password= input("Password: ")

        for user in users:
            if username == user["username"] and password == user["password"]:
                print("\nYou have succesfully been logged {}".format(user["name"], user["last_name"]))
                src.user_main_menu.main_menu()
                signed_in= True
                break
        if not signed_in:
            print("Wrong input. Try again.")
            exit = input("Enter q if you want to exit the program. : ")
            if exit == "q":
                print("Sad to see you go!")
                break
```

Comment: Just import the function and call the function to return the values?

Comment: Another option is to make a class with attributes and the login function will be a method of this class.

Comment: @Nagashayan can you write down the code that I should add. I've tried to replace the break within the first if statement with return username, password and then called it in the other module and it doesn't work?

Comment: Hard to understand what you want to accomplish. Maybe I'm just to tied. Do you just want to return `username` and `password` to whatever called `login_1`

Comment: local variables are, well, local - they are not accessible from outside the function, and actually only exist just as long as the function is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Its very simple concept. I see couple of errors in your code. like what is users? I dont see you defined it anywhere.

To simplify module importing this is what I was suggesting.

mod1.py

```
def login_1():

    username= input("Username: ")
    password= input("Password: ")
    return username, password
```

mode2.py

```
from mod1 import login_1

username, password = login_1()
```

In your code you can replace break with

> return username, password

and it should work once you fix your other code errors

Comment: Users is a variable that I loaded from the json file with a dict with users. I left that part out when posting this q. I'm going to try what you suggested first thing in the morning and also update this q if it solves it.

Comment: I tried it but without any luck. The problem is if I return the values from that function and then call it in the other module and function, it asks for the username and the password again and continues the loop. I want to get the values from that module's username and password, not ask for them again.

Comment: that was not the initial question. so please submit another question regarding this. I would suggest read about singleton pattern or class that will solve your problem.